# Get authorization for an on-line shop via api key and token

Tags: php, rest

I'm struggling with on-line shopping platform Shoplo. There is a following page in their documentation: 
http://docs.shoplo.com/api/auth

So, in order to use their API I should authenticate the client's shop first via some app. I created app, got API Key and shared key. I'm trying to get the request token as mentioned there but I do not know how. I tried to do something like this in PHP:

```
$handle = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array(
    $handle,
        array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.shoplo.com/services/oauth/request_token',
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'oauth_consumer_key=MY_KEY&oauth_consumer_secret=MY_CONSUMER_KEY',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true

        )
        );
$response = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
print_r($response);
```

I get the following message:
{"status":"err","error":210,"error_msg":"General OAuth error | Can't verify request, missing oauth_consumer_key or oauth_token"}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're setting post fields incorrectly.
Try this:

```
$postFields = array(
   'oauth_consumer_key' => 'MY_KEY', // replace it with your API KEY
   'oauth_consumer_secret' => 'MY_SECRET', // replace it with your SHARED KEY
);
```

and then:

```
$handle = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array(
    $handle,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.shoplo.com/services/oauth/request_token',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postFields,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    )
 );
```

Comment: Hi, I did what you suggested but now I get something like this: OAuth Verification Failed: Verification of signature failed (no oauth_signature in request).

Comment: Seems like you need to obtain OAuth signature for your request, as I assume you use OAuth for authentication. I'd start with verifying is OAuth reqiured for connecting to shoplo.com and if it is, i'd start reading about it [in the docs](http://php.net/manual/pl/book.oauth.php). OAuth requests are not simple cURL requests...